# Fast Writes to MongoDB Console, Slow to ReplSet

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, database-replication, mongoengine

I have a three node MongoDB replica set.

If I write to the primary node via command line, it completes quickly (< 1 sec).

If I write to the replica set via MongoEngine, it takes forever (> 45 seconds)!

I don't see anything abnormal in the logs -- just successful connections.

The data ultimately shows up, but the connections are blocking for each node.

sample insert (console):

```
start db 2014-06-17 07:34:10.771450
end db 2014-06-17 07:34:10.777390
```

sample insert (replset):

```
start db 2014-06-17 07:34:10.771450
end db 2014-06-17 07:34:50.883062
```

Connection String (MongoEngine):

`db.connect('app', host='db1, db2, db3', username='app', password='abcdef', port=27017, replicaSet='rs0')`

I tried disabling writeConcern alltogether, but that didn't help.

If I remove the `replicaSet` parameter (but keep the three hosts), it speeds right up and data syncs as intended.

What could be causing this? Am I missing anything if I leave of `replicaSet`?

Comment: You do need a replicaSet connection.  I would change to uri format and then make sure that all hosts are visible from the application.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are using a replicaSet connection, changing to the URI format:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

Ensuring you have the [replicaSet option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#replica-set-option) in the options set.

Finally, ensure that all the replicaSet hosts are accessible from the application server.